# ios objects are released in Debug mode but not being released in Release mode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My question says everything. is it even possible? this is pretty weird and I am not sure where to look or what to do. Everything is being released in simulator and when I run in app using debug mode. I can see the logs inside my dealloc methods and everything is working fine. but when i run my application in release mode. the objects are not released.

anybody else had this issue?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, ARC auto-releases object with different timing weither you're building in debug or release mode. This is due to the optimization flag of the compiler being `-O0` in debug and `-O3` or `-Os` in release.

I recall hearing an Apple engineer talking about it in one of the WWDC '13 talks (I'll try to find the session name), and from what I remember, this behaviour will be improved in the futures Xcode builds to make ARC in debug mode behave much more like it does in release mode.

I know it does not help much, but I'm not familiar enough with ARC implementation to offer more details.

See also [How do you debug an issue with a release mode build in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460281/how-do-you-debug-an-issue-with-a-release-mode-build-in-ios?rq=1) to help debug your code in release mode.

Comment: But the only cases I have seen so far were the other way around: In Release mode (with optimization) the objects are released earlier than in Debug mode (without optimization).

Answer (score 0):

Could you accidentally have Zombies turned on for release mode but off for debug? Normally all diagnostics are off for release but it would fit your description.