# iOS App Crashes when installed remote/diawi but not if installed from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, diawi

I have an iOS app which, when submitted to Apple is crashing during usage when you try to go to a new view. This also occurs if i package up the application for enterprise distribution and then go to use the app.

If i just plug the phone in and run from xcode to the device though, it runs perfectly.

Has anyone experienced this before and have any ideas what it could be? Running latest xcode and ios, not using betas.

EDIT - i've tested building straight to the device using both debug and release scehemes, and they both working, but again, only when the device is plugged into the computer and it's built straight to it. packaging it in anyway and installing remotely causes it to crash on a particular screen. The error logs end up as a basically unreadable mess at this point.

Comment: Check if you have different settings for "Debug" and "Release" mode

Comment: Where are the settings for Debug and Release? I know how to change between them but i didn't even know that there was a place to change what settings are actually behind them.

Comment: You can look into this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460281/how-do-you-debug-an-issue-with-a-release-mode-build-in-ios

Comment: You need to provide a fully symbolicated crash report with relevant code of your app. Your app not crashing when installed from Xcode does not mean your app does not have bugs that cause it to crash.

Comment: Hi, I have same issue but I can not get any solution. Please help me?

Comment: Yeah I also have the same issue. I can run from Xcode, but when I take build using diawi and try to install the app is installing. But when I open its get crashed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we archive app it mostly builds with release mode on, and when we run build on devices simply by XCode it's with debug mode on. You can check these configuration by going

`Edit Scheme` -> **Run** -> `Build configuration`, same you can check for **Archive**.

Now for tracking the crash issue you can simply try changing Run's debug mode to release mode for time being.

I got the crash where I was doing configuration for firebase for production target which has different bundle identifier than dev build identifier. You case may be different.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, to be honest, that is really odd... It really shouldn't have that affect if you distribute via enterprise... As of any idea on how to fix this issue: you did add entitlements to the app when signing via enterprise, right?