# hidden line error in crash log in device

Tags: ios, debugging, xcode7, ad-hoc-distribution

my app works fine when debugging on device and simulator ,but crashing during OTA and AD HOC distribution  , I adding here my device log , Im getting the hidden error at the first line in thread 0 :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001001435ac
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
0.471355     CFNetwork                  0x00000001839f9a80 TCP Conn 0x126183ed0 SSL Handshake DONE
0.705883     CFNetwork                  0x00000001839f9990 TCP Conn 0x126183ed0 starting SSL negotiation
0.706739     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183a9bf18 TCP Conn 0x126183ed0 complete. fd: 32, err: 0
0.708259     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183a9d444 TCP Conn 0x126183ed0 event 1. err: 0
0.748479     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183a9d51c TCP Conn 0x126183ed0 started



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   SimPlan                         0x00000001001435ac __hidden#11038_ (__hidden#11355_:122)
1   UIKit                           0x00000001888231b8 __47-[UIApplication _applicationDidEnterBackground]_block_invoke + 228
2   UIKit                           0x00000001888f36d4 +[UIViewController _performWithoutDeferringTransitions:] + 128
3   UIKit                           0x0000000188823080 -[UIApplication _applicationDidEnterBackground] + 100
4   UIKit                           0x0000000188823604 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationDeactivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:] + 700
5   UIKit                           0x0000000188833a80 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 448
6   UIKit                           0x000000018881d70c __70-[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 152
7   UIKit                           0x000000018881d394 -[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 712
8   FrontBoardServices              0x0000000184db77ac __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
9   FrontBoardServices              0x0000000184db7618 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 168
10  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000184db79c8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833cd09c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833ccb30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001833ca830 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001832f4c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
15  GraphicsServices                0x0000000184bdc088 GSEventRunModal + 180
16  UIKit                           0x00000001885de088 UIApplicationMain + 204
17  SimPlan                         0x000000010014184c main (__hidden#11355_:21)
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000182e928b8 start + 4
```

I try to debug with optimization level as suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460281/how-do-you-debug-an-issue-with-a-release-mode-build-in-ios) :

Thanks for any help!