# React-Native app is rendered different when distributed with Testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, testflight

I am currently working on a react-native app and everything went smooth so far.

But suddenly on a new testflight release the app is rendered different when distributed with testflight than when i test in the simulator or directly on devices via xcode. With different I mean that big parts of the views are simply not displayed (the app is still working and not crashing however). Previous builds worked fine on testflight.

I tried:

- Product->Clean in xCode
- New Checkout from Git
- Using Fastlane vs building & uploading manually
- Deleting app from device, restarting and reinstalling

But no success. How is that possible? i can understand that it might have different results in simulator vs real device. But real device via xcode vs testflight makes no sense to me. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried building in release mode onto the simulator and devices?

Comment: Nope didn't think of that... And you are right when i do this it is rendered like in testflight. But what might cause this difference? I thought the difference between release and debug is mainly compiler optimization (deactivating didnt help) and suprression of warnings?

Comment: It really depends on the components you're using, tiny quirks can occur due to differences in debug/release configs across all the various code you're using.

Comment: Any recommendation / best practice on how to track this down? Seems like i don't have access to any rn debugging tools in release mode like inspector or even the js console... so i am just step by step  removing and replacing view components hoping to get some insight which seem to take like forever...

Comment: There are a few routes: first - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460281/how-do-you-debug-an-issue-with-a-release-mode-build-in-ios - next: check if it's a styling problem first - i.e. is there some obscure rule which breaks the display of a component? And last, isolate the most unstable of components and work back.

Comment: What do you mean by rendered differently?

Comment: complete View items are simply not rendered. I have one base Component that is used across multiple views and has some subComponents Some of these are simply ignored when built for release but everything is rendered perfectly without warnings or errors in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably quite specific but might help someone at sometime:
Problem in my case was that one View I wrote inherited from View instead of Component.

I am still wondering why it was rendered correctly in Debug mode but broken in Release mode but

```
myView extends Component{
...
}
```

instead of

```
myView extends View{
...
}
```

solved it for me.